# Tailwind CSS custom gradient with React state and FastAverageColor

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a custom gradient over an image using React state, Tailwind CSS and the  FastAverageColor package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-average-color) into my Next JS app.
I'm using an useEffect hook for this:

```
const [avgColor, setAvgColor] = useState("")
useEffect(() => {
        const fac = new FastAverageColor()
        fac.getColorAsync(songData.track.album.images[0].url, { algorithm: 'dominant' }).then(result => {
            setAvgColor(`w-full h-full absolute bg-gradient-to-tr from-[${result.hex}] to-transparent`)
        })
}, [avgColor, songData.track.album.images])
```

The JSX is presented below:

```
        <div className="relative w-full h-full">
            <Image priority alt="test" layout='fill' objectFit='cover' src={songData.track.album.images[0].url} />
            {avgColor ? <div className={avgColor}></div> : null}
        </div>
```

The problem is that my gradient doesn't appear over the image. Do you know maybe why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do with JIT classes but you can use `from-current` and set an inline color to set the from color.

So, try this:

```
setAvgColor(result.hex)
```

and

```
<div style={{color: avgColor}} className="w-full h-full absolute bg-gradient-to-tr from-current to-transparent"></div>
```

[basic demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EP23rYFI9n)